# Is the definition of "include" incomplete in Merriam-Webster's Dictionary？

Tags: meaning, definition

This is a definition of include in the Oxford Dictionary:

1. to make sb/sth part of sth

These are all the definitions of include in Webster's Dictionary：

1. to take in or comprise as a part of a whole or group
2. to contain between or within
3. to shut up:ENCLOSE

I think the definitions in Webster's Dictionary do not express the same meaning as the definition in Oxford Dictionary. Is it my misunderstanding or is the definition in Webster's Dictionary indeed incomplete?

Comment: What aspects/meanings specifically do you feel are missing?

Comment: I'm astonished by how often non-native Anglophones keep finding what they think are "mistakes" in English dictionaries - for which they're not part of the target readership anyway.

Comment: @dubious Thank you for your comment. What I mean is that the definition in the Oxford Dictionary explains the usage of "include" in "you should include some examples in your essay", but it seems that the Webster Dictionary does not explain it.

Comment: Let me save you the trouble. Most words like this are exactly the same in BrE and AmE AND basically the same in all good dictionaries. And if you have provided the full defs. this would have been obvious to you and us.

Comment: @Endeavor the "examples in essay" meaning is covered by points 1 and 2 of Webster: to take in and to contain within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct answer: **No**; Merriam-Webster's definition #1 means pretty much the same thing as Oxford's. If I "include you in my birthday party," I am "taking you in as a part of a whole or group"—that is, my guests, and am also "making you part of something."

Longer answer: Any dictionary that tried to be *absolutely* complete, and include every way that a word is used, would be very long and hard to use. You would have to look through many entries to find the one that mattered to you. So most dictionaries try on purpose just to list the most *common* usages. The "Oxford English Dictionary" (or "OED") is one of the biggest and the most thorough; it has about 14 meanings for "include." But note, Oxford makes many other dictionaries, like a learner's dictionary, so if you find an "Oxford dictionary" definition, it might not be from the OED itself.

In general, when you're researching a word, it can be smart to start with a dictionary that uses easy language and contains the most common usages, like a learner's dictionary. If what you find there is confusing, look up the same word in a bigger dictionary (like Merriam-Webster).

Comment: Thank you very much. And I found that "to take in" has the meaning of "to include" in dictionary, so does it have the same usage as "include" (Can it replace the "include" in the structures like "include... in/on/as/with..."？). Can I replace the "include" in "We include them in our target clientele." and "You should include some examples in your essay." with "take in"?

Comment: @Endeavor Note, comments aren't meant as discussion threads. If you have a new question, open it as a new question. But first [read this entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take-in); I think it should answer it for you. If you have some uncertainties afterward, quote the entries you found so we can talk about them.